# Make first list item active on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following list of two items I'm using to filter content.

On page load, I want the first list item to be active and show the contents of "mine".

However, the second list item is showing the results instead. In order for the contents below this list to show the "My Dashboards" properly, I must click on it. I want this functionality on page load too.

I experimented with many jQuery click events on page load but nothing seems to work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filtering" class="clearfix nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="filter-item active" data-rel="mine">My Dashboards</li>
                <li class="filter-item" data-rel="allAvail">All Available Dashboards</li>
            </ul>
            
            
                <li class="mine allAvail">Item 1</li>
                <li class="mine">Item 2</li>
                <li class="mine allAvail">Item 3</li>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.filter-item').click(function(){
                // reset active class
                $('.filter-item').removeClass("active");
                // add active class to selected
                $(this).addClass("active");
                // return needed to make function work
                return false;
            });
            
            
            $(function() {
                // create an empty variable
                var selectedClass = "";
                // call function when item is clicked
                $(".filter-item").click(function(){
                    // assigns class to selected item
                    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
                    // fades out all portfolio items
                    $(".portfolio li").fadeOut(300);
                    // fades in selected category
                    $(".portfolio li." + selectedClass).delay(300).fadeIn(500);
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like everything in $(function() { ... is never being executed. If there was any typo instead of a logical problem, you would see that in the developertools.

Comment: This was hard to follow but do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/p4uLaofk/2/